# How to prove that these sequences have limits and find their value?

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

Let $f:R\longrightarrow R$,and $f(x)=x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}$,and 
$$L_{1}(x)=f(x),L_{2}(x)=f(f(x)),L_{3}(x)=f(L_{2}(x)),\cdots,L_{n}(x)=f(L_{n-1}(x))$$

and let $$a_{n}=L_{n}\left(\dfrac{17}{n}\right)$$
prove that
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(na_{n}\right)$$ is exist, and find the value limit.

my idea: I want find this 
$$L_{n}(x)=\cdots?$$  But it is very ugly, becasuse
$$L_{2}(x)=f(f(x))=\left(x-\dfrac{x^2}{2}\right)-\dfrac{(x-\dfrac{x^2}{2})^2}{2}=-\dfrac{1}{8}x^4-\dfrac{1}{2}x^3-x^2+x$$

Comment: Source?????????

Comment: You could start looking for equilibrium points by setting $f(x_{eq}) = x_{eq}$ and check whether it's stable or not.

Comment: @GerryMyerson,My frend ask me, I think can find this $L_{n}(x)$

Comment: oh,This can't find $L_{n}(x)$,sorry,

Comment: Writing $L_n(x) = x_n$ we have the recursion $x_{n+1}=x_n - x_n^2/2$. With the transformation $x_n =: 2y_n$, the recursion becomes $y_{n+1}=y_n(1 - y_n)$. This is the special case $r=1$ of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map with $y_n \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @gammatester It's not quite though because the input value depends on $n$, there's not just one fixed starting value $x_0$ that you iterate off of. Right?

Comment: @snulty: I am not sure what you mean with *because the input value depends on n.* Use $x_0=x$ and find 
$$L_1(x) = x_1 = f(x) = x-\frac{1}{2}x^2$$
$$L_2(x) = x_2 = f(f(x)) = x-x^2+\frac{1}{2}x^3-\frac{1}{8}x^4$$

Comment: @gammatester But $x_0$ depends on $n$, it's $17/n$