# What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} n a_n$?

Tags: calculus, limits, contest-math

Let $L(x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2}$ and let

$$ a_n = \underbrace{L(L(\cdots L(}_{n \text{ times}}\frac{17}{n}))\cdots).$$

I'm trying to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} n a_n$.

I don't really know how to proceed. I tried calculating the first few values of $na_n$ and plotted them and got

[image]

The limit seems to be somewhat above $1.6$. (By the way, I'm not sure why the horizontal axis is labeled like that. I plotted $na_n$ from for $n \in \{ 10, \cdots, 23 \}$, because the early values of $n a_n$ blow up. But for some reason the labeling started from $1$.)

How could I go about finding the limit? There has to be some sort of trick (this is apparently from the high school math competition "Math Prize for Girls", but I found this problem on expii), but I'm just not seeing it...

**Edit:** Frenzy Li linked to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466470/how-prove-this-sequences-have-limts-and-find-this-value) question. The question is the same, but the answer given back then (2) appears to be incorrect. (Based on computing large values, it appears to be $\frac{34}{19}$.)

Comment: Related: [Another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466470/how-prove-this-sequences-have-limts-and-find-this-value) is asked with the same setting.

Comment: @FrenzyLi But expii said the solution is $\frac{34}{19}$...?

Comment: Don't worry... I'm just pointing that this question has been asked before...

Comment: @FrenzyLi Fair enough, but the other question appears to give an incorrect answer, if the answer is in fact $\frac{34}{19}$?

Comment: @FrenzyLi Yep, I did! Fixed.

Comment: @FrenzyLi Specifically, I don't see how he goes from $\frac{a_{n+1} - a_n}{\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n}}$ to $\frac{n(n+1)a_n^2}{2}$. In the other question you linked. Because $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ have completely different inputs (i.e. $\frac{17}{n}$ and $\frac{17}{n+1}$.)

Comment: A few numbers:  When $n=10^5$, the $na_n\approx1.78944$.  When $n=10^6$, $na_n\approx1.78947$. Mathematica code: `L[x_] := x - x^2/2`, `# Nest[N[L[#]] &, 17/#, #] &[1000000]`

Comment: @FrenzyLi Aha, so it is $\frac{34}{19}$ and not $2$. Any idea on how to show it analytically?

Comment: Numerical evidence supports $\frac{34}{19}$ but unfortunately I don't know how to get this result closed-form.

Comment: If we change the $17$ to $18$, we get the limit as $1.8$ which is $\frac{36}{20}$.  If we change to $a_n = L(L(\cdots L(\frac{k}{n}))\cdots)$, the limit appears to be $\lim_{n \to \infty} n a_n=\frac{2k}{k+2}$.  On an unrelated note, if $\lim_{k\to+\infty}\lim_{n \to \infty} n a_n=2$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To compute $na_n$ we start with $y=17$  and apply $n$ times the transformation
$$y_{new}=nL(y/n)=y-y^2/(2n)$$
i.e.
$$(y_{new}-y)/\epsilon=-y^2/2$$
where $\epsilon=1/n$.
For $n\to \infty$ this means that we're solving the ODE
$$y'=-y^2/2$$
with the initial condition $y(0)=17$, and want to know $y(1)$. The solutions of the ODE are $y(x)=2/(x+c)$, $y(0)=17$ gives $c=2/17$, hence $y(1)=34/19$.

**edit**: In more detail: for a given $n$ we define a function 
$$y_n:\{0,\frac1n,\frac2n,\frac3n,\dots,1\}\to \mathbb R$$
via
$$y_n(0)=17,\quad y\bigl(x+\frac1n\bigr)=y(x)-\frac{y(x)^2}{2n}$$
and then extend $y_n$ to a piecewise-linear function $[0,1]\to \mathbb R$. We have $y_n(1)=na_n$. This function $y_n$ is also the outcome of the Euler approximate method of solving the ODE $y'=-y^2/2$ with the initial condition $y(0)=17$ and with the step $1/n$. The sequence $y_n$ converges to a solution of the ODE - that's true for any ODE whenever the RHS is (say) locally Lipschitz in $y$. Not sure about a textbook reference, here is what I found on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/a/200412/9390

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this turns into $y' = -y^2/2$ as $n \to \infty$? I only know the basics of ODEs and haven't taken a full course in diffeq yet.

Comment: hopefully it's clearer after the edits

Comment: Why the continuous solution and the discrete solution are the same?

Comment: That is a point that needs to be proved.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio What I'm really using is that the Euler approximate (discrete) method of solving ODEs converges to a solution for the ODE for  nice enough ODEs

Comment: @user8268: but the logistic map is highly sensitive to the initial conditions, while the continuous equivalent is not, so something still needs to be shown.

Comment: @user8268: all right, $a_{n+1}$ is not $f(a_n)$, but I still think that the switch to the continuous equivalent and the claim that the limit is the same has to be properly justified.

Comment: I can't figure out why you apply $nL(y/n)$. Is it not start with $y=17/n$, then apply $L$ $n$ times , then multiply by $n$?

Comment: @snulty if $K(y):=nL(y/n)$ then $na_n=K(K\dots(K(17))\dots)=nL(L\dots(L(17/n))\dots)$ ($n$ $K$'s and $L$'s)

Answer (score 1):

@user8268's answer is amazing. I was shocked to see how ideas derived from numerical method could benefit problems that are totally unrelated at first glance. Just want to add a few things.

As mentioned in the answer. The ODE discretization is in $[0, 1]$ with resolution $1/n$. The figure below shows the dsicretization with $n = 8, 16, 32, 64$. $n=8$ corresponds to the bottom curve, $n=16$ corresponds to the second to bottom curve, and so on. The convergence is apparent.
[image: Bottom to top, n = 8, 16, 32, 64]

Another interesting observation is the solution "blows up" numerically for $n = 7$(not shown), and becomes negative for $n = 8$. Those erroneous behaviors is very common in numerical solutions of ODE where the resolution is insufficient. Here we can estimate the minimum resolution required.

The discretization is

$$
y^{i+1} = y^i \left( 1 - \frac{y^i}{2n} \right)
$$
To maintain the positive definiteness, we must have $n > y^i/2$. Apparent $y$ is decreasing according to the ODE, so $\max(y) = y^0 = 17$, then we have $n > 17/2$ or $n = 9$.